# Xcode Swift Remove MKPolyline

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I am writing an app that has the ability to track a user's location and trace it on a map. There are three buttons, one that starts tracing the path that the user lays down, one is to stop tracing the path the user lays down, and the last is to clear the map of the traced line. I am having trouble setting up the clear button. Can someone please help me set up the @IBAction for the clear path button.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var theMap: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var startStopTracking: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var clearPath: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var manager:CLLocationManager!
    var myLocations: [CLLocation] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Setup our Location Manager
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        //manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //Setup our Map View
        theMap.delegate = self
        theMap.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
        theMap.showsUserLocation = true

        //Setup startStopTracking button?

        startStopTracking.selectedSegmentIndex = -1
    }

    @IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
            switch startStopTracking.selectedSegmentIndex
            {
            case 0:
                manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            case 1:
                manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            default:
                break;
            }
    }

    @IBAction func clearPath(sender: UIButton) {
        //label.text = String(myLocations.count)
        //stopTracking()
        //theMap.removeOverlay(overlay: MKOverlay) -> Void
    }

    func stopTracking() {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        myLocations = []
    }

    func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
        //theLabel.text = "\(locations[0])"
        myLocations.append(locations[0] as CLLocation)

        let spanX = 0.007
        let spanY = 0.007
        var newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: theMap.userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
        theMap.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)

        if (myLocations.count > 1){
            var sourceIndex = myLocations.count - 1
            var destinationIndex = myLocations.count - 2

            let c1 = myLocations[sourceIndex].coordinate
            let c2 = myLocations[destinationIndex].coordinate
            var a = [c1, c2]
            var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: a.count)
            theMap.addOverlay(polyline)
        }
    }


    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {

        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 6
            return polylineRenderer
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You were on the right track with `removeOverlay`; what's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

try this : removes all

```
   for poll in mapkit.overlays {

        mapkit.removeOverlay(poll)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your `polyline` a class property so you have access to it in your clearPath method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
    ...
    var polyline: MKPolyline = MKPolyline()


    @IBAction func clearPath(sender: UIButton) {
        //label.text = String(myLocations.count)
        //stopTracking()
        theMap.removeOverlay(polyline)
    }

}
```

Comment: Not necessarily. He could look through the map view's `overlays` to find it. Perhaps this is the only overlay, in which case it's trivial to find it.

Comment: @matt: You are right, thats a simpler (and clearer) solution.

Comment: How is what you're talking about different than the solution in the code above? @matt

Comment: @Chris We are both assuming that your problem is that you do not know how to get a reference to your own overlay - it isn't clear. You have not, in response to my original query, clarified what the problem is. But since you know about `removeOverlay` one can guess that you just don't know what overlay to remove. OK, so we gave two solutions. zisoft said "Keep a reference to the overlay when you create it, so you can remove it later." I said, "Perhaps there's no need to keep a reference to it, seeing that the map view is already keeping a reference to it for you."

Comment: `MKMapView` has a property `overlays` which holds an array of all overlays associated to the map. You can iterate through that array and remove the overlays that way.

Comment: I seem to be missing something still. I am a beginner so maybe there is some miscommunication. In my app I want there to be a map with buttons on the bottom. I have a segmented controller that will start and stop tracing a line behind the users location. The problem is I want to have a button named clearpath to remove the path laid by the starttracking method but I can't figure that part out.